# VSCode Omnisharp analyzing code twice for duplicate windows

Tags: visual-studio-code, omnisharp

I'm using VSCode for Unity development.
I've noticed that when I open the project in VSCode, from Unity, it takes a long time to analyze my project. Is there some caching mechanism that I'm not familiar with? It currently takes about 20min+.

I also tend to open a duplicate window with the same workspace which triggers Omnisharp to analyze all the files again.

Is there a way to at least have a single analysis of the project?

[image]

Duplicate window

[image]

PS
I have no idea why the file count is different. The solution is the same.